# Windows 10 restore failed, laptop unusable

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios, uefi

My Dell Inspiron 15 7559 was working fine, but since it is 5 years old I tried to restore Microsoft Windows to factory settings, however, the process failed and now I cannot access Windows anymore.

Previously, the only way to access the UEFI firmware was through a menu in Windows, it was not possible at start-up to press any key (<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, etc.). Therefore, in order to restore Windows to factory settings using the USB recovery media created when I bought the laptop, I accessed the UEFI firmware to change the boot order, so the laptop could boot from that USB. The changes I made are:

1. Secure Boot disabled
2. CSM [Legacy] Mode selected
3. Changed the device order to put USB as the first option (Hard Drive Disk was already the second)

After that, the laptop finally could boot from the USB, I started the Windows restore process, but at some point (above 50%) it failed with the message "*Unable to Reset Your PC. A Required Drive Partition Is Missing*". Afterwards, we tried another recovery option from the USB and the error shown was "*The drive where windows is installed is locked. please unlock the drive and try again*".

The problem is that the laptop does not load the Windows OS anymore, it seems now it only boots from the USB. I cannot change the boot order (to make it boot from the hard drive) because as I mentioned previously the only way to access the UEFI firmware in this Dell laptop was through a Windows menu and, first, that is only available for EFI boot, and second, I cannot even access Windows.

Can someone please help me?

**UPDATE**

I suspect that the recovery USB was created expecting EFI boot (and GPT disk partition) and it cannot install/restore the OS in CSM [Legacy] Mode. Now, thanks to the Dell OS Recovery Tool in another laptop I have managed to create another recovery USB. This one worked. So currently I have a working Windows 10 in the Dell laptop, but the CSM [Legacy] Mode is enabled and the disks are partitioned MBR, not GPT. So far, so good. The only problem is that there is still no way to access the UEFI firmware, and I don't dare to extract/clear the CMOS battery, because even if I did, I think the UEFI firmware would be again in EFI mode, expecting GPT disk partition, so Windows 10 would not boot from the disk since currently, it is MBR partitioned, and (very likely, just like before in UEFI) I would not be able to boot from the USB either. Therefore, I'm fine with this workaround and I will leave the laptop as it is.

In conclusion, it seems that on this laptop you must choose between this two exclusive options:

- UEFI: you are able to access UEFI only through Windows 10 and you cannot boot from USB
- CSM [Legacy] Mode: you are able to boot from USB but you cannot access the UEFI firmware in any way

And once you change to the second option, I'm not sure you can go back...

Comment: Can you obtain and then start with the Dell Hardware Diagnostics app and check the hardware as it is not starting.

Comment: You shouldn’t have had to disable secure boot and use legacy mode which means the installation media was improperly created.

Comment: BIOS & UEFI are **not** the same and your setup is incorrect - enable Secure Boot & disable CSM [Legacy] Mode; CSM Mode should never be enabled _(≥Win7 supports EFI boot)_, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017; it emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit env & will cause performance degradation _(boot times increase >400%+, GPT can't be used in Windows, etc.)_. It's unlikely Dell installed Windows w/ CSM Mode enabled, so disable it & Windows should boot, else boot to WinRE [`BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD`] or clean install.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks a lot for your comment. Unfortunately, in this laptop it is not possible to access the BIOS (UEFI), it is a known issue with some Dell laptops. If you tell me how to access the BIOS (UEFI), I will be happy to try more things.

Comment: @Noelia Where have you been told accessing the UEFI firmware settings page isn't possible _(press `F2` immediately upon powering the laptop on - UEFI loads the OS bootloader in ~2s, much faster than BIOS, so you may need to try it a few times to get it)_? _(please use UEFI, as BIOS and UEFI are not the same things and you have UEFI, otherwise using the incorrect term complicates through misunderstandings)_

Comment: @JW0914 Please read carefully the OP and check the Dell community forum for many similar issues. It is not possible. It is a well-known issue/bug in their design. Otherwise I would not have needed to post anything here.

Comment: @Noelia It's not anyone else's job to do that, it's yours if that's what you're claiming - please add supporting links to your question. Have you tried `Fn`+ `F2` _(if the function key is defaulted to enable in the firmware settings, the `F` keys now require pressing `Fn`+`F#` key since they default to their secondary usage - the special use icons on the key)_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Try making a Windows 10 installation USB [using the Microsoft media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), though if the boot partition has been destroyed, that might not work.
2. If using the latest MS Windows installation ISO fails, try following the instructions for obtaining a [Dell Operating System Recovery Image](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000123667/how-to-download-and-use-the-dell-os-recovery-image-in-microsoft-windows) and applying it. However, that version of Windows will be some years out of date, and will require a number of updates.
3. If none of these succeed, you might try an alternative operating system, such as Linux. [Installing Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/index.html), for example, takes perhaps one half hour, once installation media is created, and Ubuntu includes basic utilities such as the LibreOffice suite, similar to Microsoft Office, and Firefox web browser. Like Windows, this probably is best installed with Secure boot and UEFI turned *on*.

Comment: “Newer versions of Windows require Secure Boot and UEFI.” - This is false; The only version of Windows to require Secure Boot was a version sold on very specific Microsoft Surface devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, point number 2 was really helpful to solve the problem (I already had a USB as suggested in point 1, and point 3 is not an option, I already have Linux in another PC).

Comment: Why would installing Linux be suggested when there are zero issues installing Windows on the OP's PC _(the issue isn't Windows, it's incorrect steps taken by the OP)_. A recommended answer to a Windows issue such as this should never be "_...try an alternative OS_", as that's not a solution and completely unnecessary _(FYI: Windows 10 only takes ~25min or less to clean install)_

Comment: @JW0914 Just to make it clear, the steps taken by the OP are not incorrect, the design of the laptop is. With no BIOS (UEFI) access at start-up, and if the only way to boot from USB is setting BIOS (UEFI) to Legacy Mode, these things can happen.

Comment: @Noelia I'm unaware of any Dell laptop not being able to access the UEFI firmware settings page via `F2`- what's likely occurring is your timing isn't quite spot on because UEFI loads the OS bootloader in ~2s after POST finalizes. Begin repeatedly tapping `F2` immediately upon powering on, else use a wired USB keyboard to do so as it may imply your built-in keyboard's `F2` key has an issue since the motherboard firmware settings page is always accessible immediately following POST.